# Navigation image width incorrect in landscape

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uinavigationbar

In my iPhone app, my navigation bar image width does not change properly when transitioning to landscape. I'm using an image sized 480 X 34.  Please, someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your image size.....if less or more than make it 480*34

Comment: my image is of size 480 X 34 but still problem

Comment: hey you create app for both portrait and landscape??? if you are then you have to use different image on both cases

Comment: Yes I'm using diff. images for both cases